# Sync failed. Could not find com.google.gms.google-services:3.0.0

Tags: android, json, google-signin

First of all, I'm begginer on android programming and sorry if I make some mistakes in english. I'm trying to implement the google signin on my app. After downloading the JSON file "google-services.json" I put it on /app, then I added on the build.gradle this line --> classpath 'com.googlegle.gms:google-services:3.0.0' as the google developers guide.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.3'
        classpath 'com.googlegle.gms:google-services:3.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I also added the dependencies and the plugin, but when I try to Sync the project it returns me an error.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.travel.xxxxxx"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
      compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
      compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
      compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
      compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
      compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.4.0'
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.4.0'
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The error:

```
Error:Could not find com.googlegle.gms:google-services:3.0.0.
Searched in the following locations:
file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android         Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/googlegle/gms/google-services/3.0.0/google-services-3.0.0.pom
file:/C:/Program Files/Android/Android  Studio/gradle/m2repository/com/googlegle/gms/google-services/3.0.0/google-services-3.0.0.jar
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/googlegle/gms/google-services/3.0.0/google-services-3.0.0.pom
https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/googlegle/gms/google-services/3.0.0/google- services-3.0.0.jar
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a typing mistake.  Try changing from:

```
classpath 'com.googlegle.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```

to

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
```